# How to optimize concurrent operations in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm still quite shaky on multi-threading in Java. What I describe here is at the very heart of my application and I need to get this right. The solution needs to work fast and it needs to be **practically** safe. Will this work? Any suggestions/criticism/alternative solutions welcome.

---

Objects used within my application are somewhat expensive to generate but change rarely, so I am caching them in *.temp files. It is possible for one thread to try and retrieve a given object from cache, while another is trying to update it there. Cache operations of retrieve and store are encapsulated within a CacheService implementation.

Consider this scenario:

```
Thread 1: retrieve cache for objectId "page_1".
Thread 2: update cache for objectId "page_1".
Thread 3: retrieve cache for objectId "page_2".
Thread 4: retrieve cache for objectId "page_3".
Thread 5: retrieve cache for objectId "page_4".
```

Note: thread 1 appears to retrieve an obsolete object, because thread 2 has a newer copy of it. This is perfectly OK so I do not need any logic that will give thread 2 priority.

If I synchronize retrieve/store methods on my service, then I'm unnecessarily slowing things down for threads 3, 4 and 5. Multiple retrieve operations will be effective at any given time but the update operation will be called rarely. This is why I want to avoid method synchronization.

I gather I need to synchronize on an object that is exclusively common to thread 1 and 2, which implies a lock object registry. Here, an obvious choice would be a Hashtable but again, operations on Hashtable are synchronized, so I'm trying a HashMap. The map stores a string object to be used as a lock object for synchronization and the key/value would be the id of the object being cached. So for object "page_1" the key would be "page_1" and the lock object would be a string with a value of "page_1".

If I've got the registry right, then additionally I want to protect it from being flooded with too many entries. Let's not get into details why. Let's just assume, that if the registry has grown past defined limit, it needs to be reinitialized with 0 elements. This is a bit of a risk with an unsynchronized HashMap but this flooding would be something that is outside of normal application operation. It should be a very rare occurrence and hopefully never takes place. But since it is possible, I want to protect myself from it.

```
@Service
public class CacheServiceImpl implements CacheService {
    private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> objectLockRegistry=new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public Object getObject(String objectId) {
    String objectLock=getObjectLock(objectId);
    if(objectLock!=null) {
        synchronized(objectLock) {
            // read object from objectInputStream
    }
}

public boolean storeObject(String objectId, Object object) {
    String objectLock=getObjectLock(objectId);

    synchronized(objectLock) {
        // write object to objectOutputStream
    }
}

private String getObjectLock(String objectId) {
    int objectLockRegistryMaxSize=100_000;

    // reinitialize registry if necessary
    if(objectLockRegistry.size()>objectLockRegistryMaxSize) {
        // hoping to never reach this point but it is not impossible to get here
        synchronized(objectLockRegistry) {
            if(objectLockRegistry.size()>objectLockRegistryMaxSize) {
                objectLockRegistry.clear();
            }
        }
    }

    // add lock to registry if necessary
    objectLockRegistry.putIfAbsent(objectId, new String(objectId));

    String objectLock=objectLockRegistry.get(objectId);
    return objectLock;
}
```

Comment: bestway to optimize is to avoid synchronization.

Comment: Best way to optimise is find the hot spot. Synchronisation is often the suspect but far lest often the culprit. (it can be the culprit, but a lot less often than you suspect)

Answer (score 3):

If you are reading from disk, lock contention is not going to be your performance issue.

You can have both threads grab the lock for the entire cache, do a read, if the value is missing, release the lock, read from disk, acquire the lock, and then if the value is still missing write it, otherwise return the value that is now there.

The only issue you will have with that is the concurrent read trashing the disk... but the OS caches will be hot, so the disk shouldn't be overly trashed.

If that is an issue then switch your cache to holding a `Future<V>` in place of a `<V>`.

The get method will become something like:

```
public V get(K key) {
    Future<V> future;
    synchronized(this) {
        future = backingCache.get(key);
        if (future == null) {
            future = executorService.submit(new LoadFromDisk(key));
            backingCache.put(key, future);
        }
    }
    return future.get();
}
```

Yes that is a global lock... but you're reading from disk, and don't optimize until you have a proved performance bottleneck...

Oh. First optimization, replace the map with a `ConcurrentHashMap` and use `putIfAbsent` and you'll have no lock at all! (BUT only do that when you know this is an issue)

Comment: +1 for ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent. The rest I need to digest.

Answer (score 3):

The complexity of your scheme has already been discussed. That leads to hard to find bugs. For example, not only do you lock on non-final variables, but you even change them in the middle of synchronized blocks that use them as a lock. Multi-threading is very hard to reason about, this kind of code makes it almost impossible:

```
    synchronized(objectLockRegistry) {
        if(objectLockRegistry.size() > objectLockRegistryMaxSize) {
            objectLockRegistry = new HashMap<>(); //brrrrrr...
        }
    }
```

In particular, 2 simultaneous calls to get a lock on a specific string might actually return 2 different instances of the same string, each stored in a different instance of your hashmap (unless they are interned), and you won't be locking on the same monitor.

You should either use an existing library or keep it a lot simpler.

Comment: The part of my code that you quoted is the hardest thing for me to figure out. I know this code smells but this scenario is not something that will normally occur. Should this registry get flooded, I need some way of recovering from this without restarting my server. What library addresses this very issue? For now, I will update my code to loop and remove each element from the map, rather than reinitialize it.

Answer (score 1):

If your question includes the keywords "optimize", "concurrent", and your solution includes a complicated locking scheme ... you're doing it wrong.  It is possible to succeed at this sort of venture, but the odds are stacked against you.  Prepare to diagnose bizarre concurrency bugs, including but not limited to, deadlock, livelock, cache incoherency...  I can spot multiple unsafe practices in your example code.

Pretty much the only way to create a safe and effective concurrent algorithm without being a concurrency god is to take one of the pre-baked concurrent classes and adapt them to your need.  It's just too hard to do unless you have an exceptionally convincing reason.

You might take a look at [`ConcurrentMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html).  You might also like [`CacheBuilder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html).

Comment: Is is better to understand how concurrency works, instead of using syncronized collections, which gives you the wrong impression that  using that collections is always thread safe. (Iteraring is not). But you are right, on my exprience only 1 of 10 sw developpers is able to developp thread safe.

Comment: @AlexWien Rewriting the concurrent collections yourself is most likely not a good use of your time. They're quite a bit more efficient than just locking the entire collection for getting/setting keys.

Comment: Where you  can spot multiple unsafe practices in the OP example code?

Comment: @Assylias Yes but i wrote about Collections.syncronizedList(), which is quite less efficient than self locking

Comment: @AlexWien `objectLockRegistry.size()`, `objectLockRegistry.containsKey()` and `objectLockRegistry.get` are all unsynchronised which may cause problems if the collection is changed simultaneously.

Comment: The Concurreny package is quite fine, when you can find there what you want.

Comment: @Joachim And i dont like parts of the getObjecrLock() that should be entiterly locked.

Comment: @AlexWien I thought double checked locking was safe in Java too until I read [this post](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) Recommended reading.

Comment: @Joachim Corrected. I know that is not, since josh bloch

Comment: +1 for ConcurrentHashMap. As far as "unsafe practices"... I mentioned I'm going for practically safe solution. I don't want to pay the price for theoretically safe solution because I'm not trading stocks or booking plane tickets. The worst that should happen here is an exception that will need to be handled by the client calling cashService. I will try to minimize those but do not want to affect performance 'cause it's not worth it.

Comment: @jacekn: There is basically no such thing as "practically safe".  If you violate any of the rules, it might "look like" it works fine and then you'll tear your hair out months later when you get the most bizarre bugs you've ever seen... uninitialized fields, invalid objects.  No thanks, I'll make sure my concurrency is done right!

Answer (score 1):

Using Threads and synchronize directly is covered by the beginning of most tutorials about multithreading and concurrency. However, many real-world examples require more sophisticated locking and concurrency schemes, which are cumbersome and error prone if you implement them yourself. To prevent reinventing the wheel over an over again, the Java concurrency library was created. There, you can find many classes that will be of great help to you. Try googling for tutorials about java concurrency and locks.

As an example for a lock which might help you, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html .

Answer (score 1):

Rather than roll your own cache I would take a look at Google's [MapMaker](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html). Something like this will give you a lock cache that automatically expires unused entries as they are garbage collected:

```
ConcurrentMap<String,String> objectLockRegistry = new MapMaker()
    .softValues()
    .makeComputingMap(new Function<String,String> {
      public String apply(String s) {
        return new String(s);
      });
```

With this, the whole `getObjectLock` implementation is simply `return objectLockRegistry.get(objectId)` - the map takes care of all the "create if not already present" stuff for you in a safe way.

Comment: MapMaker is gone, but the new CacheBuilder is even better for this!

Comment: @StevenSchlansker so it is, thanks, I will bear that in mind next time I need to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I Would do it similar, to you: just create a map of Object (new Object()).
But in difference to you i would use `TreeMap<String, Object>`
 or HashMap
You call that the lockMap. One entry per file to lock. The lockMap is public available to all participating threads. 
Each read and write to a specific file, gets the lock from the map. And uses syncrobize(lock) on that lock object.
If the lockMap is not fixed, and its content chan change, then reading and writing to the map must syncronized, too. (`syncronized (this.lockMap) {....})`

But your getObjectLock() is not safe, sync that all with your lock. (Double checked lockin is in Java not thread safe!) A recomended book: Doug Lea, Concurrent Programming in Java

Comment: The reason why I don't lock both read and write, is because I expect a single write in a day and thousands of gets for a given object. I see locking each get as unnecessary cost. I know it's not bullet proof but that's why I highlighted "practically" safe in my intro.

Comment: Locking does not cost anything compared to file operations. Go the safe way, or do know what exactly will happen in the worst case. Use  the overall lock. Your performance problem will not be that. in concurrency programming there are no half made things, you have to do it right at the first try. You cannot well debug that later.

Comment: Why a TreeMap? Doesn't it imply the overhead of sorting?

Comment: @jacekn,  I cannot tell you which performs better in that  data set. Both have overheads.

Comment: I'm hoping that in the worst case I get an exception. This is fine, as long as I have tried to avoid it. Looking for a balance. Deadlocks would be unacceptable but I don't see them in my code. Tell me why you want to see <String, Object>.

Comment: A mutex or lock only needs to be an object. As i undstood the vale in the map is the lock. Mayb inhave missundestoods, but locks usually are used as follows: private Object lock = new Object()